# First row in css image gallery is getting messed up?

Tags: css

So I'm trying to make an image gallery with css and in a row of 5 images, the first four on the first row get messed up and go in a diagonal line. But the weird thing is that all the others are aligned perfectly? I've tried changing the margins but nothing works. This is my css:

```
#gallery img {
margin-left: 5px; 
width: 50px;
border-radius: 50px; 
border: 4px solid #ffffff;
display: block;
float: left;
position: relative;
}

#gallery {
margin: 20px; 
width: 350px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: please also post your html. a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) would be helpful

Comment: it might be clear:both issue but not sure as no working demo so please provide demo..thanx

Answer (score 0):

Try to align the image centre using

```
.aclass {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This will push the margin from the left and right as much ass possible making it align dead centre